# Get mapped foreign key field name, Entity Framework v6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to retrieve the mapped field (`country_city`) to foreign key property (`country`) to change the value based on my scenario.

I have these entities:

```
public partial class tCity
{
    public int id_city { get; set; }
    public int number_city { get; set; }
    public string name_city { get; set; }

    // foreign key
    public string country_city { get; set; }
    public tCountry country { get; set; }
}

public partial class tCountry
{
    public int id_country { get; set; }
    public int number_country { get; set; }
    public string name_country { get; set; }
}
```

and this repository `AddedEvent`:

```
public class SecondryRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private void BaseRepository_EntityAdded(T Entity)
    {
         var __id = (int)typeof(T).GetProperties()
                                  .First(w => w.Name.StartsWith("id_"))
                                  .GetValue(Entity);
         var __dbEntity = _DbSet.Find(__id);
         var objectContext = ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)_DbContext).ObjectContext;
         var relMgr = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetRelationshipManager(__dbEntity);

         // I can find property "public tCountry country { get; set; }" from this
         var relEnds = relMgr.GetAllRelatedEnds();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to get the field `country_city` as mapped to country property  from the `relEnds` list?

Comment: it's not clear what you want to achieve